# Как записать переменную из spinBox, а потом передать её в другую форму?

Tags: c++, qt

Доброго дня. У меня есть форма `MainWindow` и форма `ksp_ecology`. На форме `MainWindow` есть `spinBox` и объявлена переменная  `double Mkrt`в `mainwindow.cpp`. Как в неё записать значение из `spinBox` и передать в форму `ksp_ecology` по нажатой кнопки pushButton.

mainwindow.cpp:

```
...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    double Mkrt = ui->spinBox->value();             
    ksp_ecology *ksp_e= new ksp_ecology();
    ksp_e->show();

}
...
```

ksp_ecology.cpp:

```
...
ksp_ecology::~ksp_ecology()
{
    delete ui;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно значение на момент показа формы, то можно через параметры конструктора:

```
class ksp_ecology : public QWidget{
    double _Mkrt;
public:
    explicit ksp_ecology(double Mkrt, QWidget *parent = 0):
        QWidget(parent),
        _Mkrt(Mkrt)
    {}
    //...
};
```

А при показе делайте так:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    double Mkrt = ui->spinBox->value();             
    ksp_ecology *ksp_e= new ksp_ecology(Mkrt, this);
    ksp_e->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    ksp_e->show();  
}
```

Обратите внимание на это:

```
    ksp_e->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

Без этого у вас у течка памяти. При каждом нажатии кнопки форма создается, и никогда не удаляется. А так она будет самоуничтожаться при закрытии.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как проверить что пришло в переменной _Mkrt? ui->spinBox_8->setValue(_Mkrt); вы летает с ошибкой

Comment: А всё . #include <QDebug> и qDebug() << _Mkrt; помогли

Comment: Вот только ругается на  ksp_ecology->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); . Такая ошибка : expected unqualified-id before '->' token... надо исправить на ksp_e->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

Comment: @Triumphov, точно, опечатался